# How to get the Vaadin 7 application server IP and port?

Tags: java, vaadin7

How can I get the protocol, IP and port of the app server running my Vaadin webapp? I'm using Vaadin 7.

In vaadin 6 I doing in this way, but not work in vaadin 7:

```
String server = ((WebApplicationContext) this.getContext()).getHttpSession().getServletContext().getServerInfo();

java.net.URL url = this.getURL();
String s = url.getHost()+":"+url.getPort()+url.getPath();
```

Answer (score 14):

```
System.out.println(UI.getCurrent().getPage().getLocation().getHost());
System.out.println(UI.getCurrent().getPage().getLocation().getPath());
System.out.println(UI.getCurrent().getPage().getLocation().getPort());
```

Answer (score 7):

I do it like this:

```
String basePath = Page.getCurrent().getLocation().getScheme() + ":" +
                  Page.getCurrent().getLocation().getSchemeSpecificPart()
```

Answer (score 2):

as for the application path part, to get the real application directory and not the browser request path, use `VaadinServlet.getCurrent().getServletContext().getContextPath()`