# How I can get an url of the window?

Tags: java, window, vaadin, vaadin6

I use java and vaadin

I do window.getURL() and it returns me, for example - 99.22.22.22:8080/2/
However, it's supposed to return app.server.com/2/

of course, app.server.com is the same as 99.22.22.22:8080

But how I can replace it by app.server.com??

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer [How to get the Vaadin 7 application server IP and port?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21788023/how-to-get-the-vaadin-7-application-server-ip-and-port) i guess.

Please try this:

```
System.out.println(UI.getCurrent().getPage().getLocation().getHost());
System.out.println(UI.getCurrent().getPage().getLocation().getPath());
System.out.println(UI.getCurrent().getPage().getLocation().getPort());
```

Or get hostname by ip:

```
InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("99.22.22.22");
String host = addr.getHostName();
System.out.println(host);
```

Comment: Yeah, if I use getHost(), I get - 99.22.22.22:8080

Comment: how I can get app.server.com ??

Comment: Is your app online and able to connect to dns?

Comment: my app is online and its available by app.server.com (for example)

Comment: How about getUriFragment()?